# How to use the pull model in Azure Cosmos DB with Java?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

In the [documentation of the pull model](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-pull-model) you can read that the pull model is only available for .NET. It there a possible to emulate the FeedIterator in Java? Is there any beta that support this already?

Answer (score 0):

The method `queryChangeFeed` from the `CosmosContainer` or `CosmosAsyncContainer` class seems to return an Iterable. See the [unit test](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/test/java/com/azure/cosmos/CosmosContainerChangeFeedTest.java) for an sample.